# How to get all players in list with min values

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to return the winners of my game with the lowest attempts. But I am unsure how to do this for cases where there is a tie.

my to get the winner is

```
try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("result.txt"))){
                while(scan.hasNext()){
                    String[] s = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
                    players.add(new Players(s[0],s[1],Integer.valueOf(s[2])));
                }
                Collections.sort(players, Comparator.comparing((players1) -> players1.getAttempts()));
                //test// System.out.println(players);
                //Collections.sort(players, (a,b)->a.getAttempts().compareTo(b.getAttempts()));


                System.out.println("The winner is: "+ players.get(0).getName() +", with "+players.get(0).getAttempts()+ " attempt(s)!");
            }
            result.close();
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: what need to do at tie case?

Comment: Display that there are is a tie for first place and then list the name of the player, with the attempts

Comment: What are the attributes and their corresponding type in `new Players(s[0],s[1],Integer.valueOf(s[2])`? Also, based on values, you're doing no comparison currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort the list in ascending order based on the attempts

```
List<Players> sortedList = players.stream().sorted((a,b)->a.getAttempts().compareTo(b.getAttempts())).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Then print all winners having least attempts

```
sortedList.stream().filter(i->i.getAttempts()==sortedList.stream().findFirst()
  .get().getAttempts()).forEach(winner->System.out.println("The winners are "+winner.getvalues));
```

or simply stream your collection object that sorted in ascending order

```
players.filter(i->i.getAttempts()==players.get(0).getAttempts()).forEach(winner->System.out.println("The winners are "+winner.getvalues));
```

Comment: for filter it says cannot find symbol could you explain this?

Comment: made some change check it @comp

Comment: this time .Collect is saying cannot find symbol

Comment: sorry `collect()` lowercase letters

Comment: then so simple just change this line `a.getAttempts().compareTo(b.getAttempts())` like this

Comment: it should only print "The winners are" when there is a tie, otherwise "the winner is". @Deadpool

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
//read file into stream, try-with-resources
 try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("result.txt"))) {
            stream.map(line -> line.split("\\s"))
                  .map(a -> new Players(a[0], a[1], Integer.parseInt(a[2])))
                  .collect(groupingBy(Players::getAttemps))
                  .entrySet().stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey))
                  .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                  .map(l -> l.size() > 1 ?
                            l.stream().map(Players::getName)
                             .collect(joining(", ","there is a tie -->", 
                                     "with "+ l.get(0).getAttemps()+"attempt(s)!")) :
                           "The winner is: " + l.get(0).getName() +
                                   "with "+ l.get(0).getAttemps() +"attempt(s)!")
                  .ifPresent(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

This handles, both the cases where there is only a single winner or when there is a tie and displays appropriate messages for each.

imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.*;
```